# Python: Find highest value in neighborhood in a 3D array (stack of images)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I use a template matching algorithm to detect instances of a given object in a target image.
The algorithm produces a heatmap looking like this:

[image]

So far I have used `skimage.feature.peak_local_max` to find the local peaks in the heatmap which worked well.

Now I want to run the template matching for different rotations of the template which will give me several heatmaps. Like these:

[image]

I have stacked these images on top of each other to create a 3D array and now I want to find the highest values in the local *neighborhood*. The neighborhood is for example defined as 15 pixels wide and high (but includes all rotations).

The 3D array is of shape *(height, width, rotation)*. The z-axis corresponds to the rotation of the template.

**EDIT:**
I have found a solution myself (with the helpful comments from *markuscosinus*) and will post this here in case anyone has the same problem:

I looked at the implementation of `scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter` (which can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIhdm.png). I twitched the code slightly to work with my data shape and used `footprint = np.ones((size_neighborhood, size_neighborhood, nr_rotations))`.

Comment: Read the arrays, Use `np.vstack` or `np.row_stack` accordingly and use `np.max()` with axis=1

Comment: This approach won't work because the information about the order of images are lost. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is the following:

1. Find local maxima for each rotation using `skimage.feature.peak_local_max`
2. For every maximum `m` at `(x,y,z)` found in step 1 check if there were found others in the neighbourhood. Easiest case would be to check the neighbourhood cube with corners `(x-n,y-n,y-n)` and `(x+n,y+n,y+n)`, where `n` is the neighbourhood size. If there are some in the neighbourhood, only keep the largest.

I know, this is not very pleasing in terms of efficiency, but in case you do not have too many or too large pictures it should get the job done :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have indeed done something similar already, the problem is that peaks from different rotations can be several pixels away. In the second step you would then have to search in the neighborhood and then it is easy to mix up peaks from several hits.

Comment: "peaks from different rotations can be several pixels away", doesn't this just mean, that there are two local maxima in this case?

Comment: If `(x,y,z)` is local maximum in `z` rotation and is bigger than `(x,y,z+1)` and `(x,y,z-1)` it is by definition a local maximum.
Of course `(x+2,y,z+1)` may be much bigger, but `(x,y,z)` is still a maximum

Comment: So maybe what you are looking for is not all local maxima, but more like all the highest values of every 'big peak'?

Comment: Yes you are right. I suppose the word *local maximum* is not the best fit here then. What I mean is the maximum value in the *neighborhood*.
I will edit the post.

Comment: Edited the post, allthough you may thought of this yourself already and didn't like it (which I can fully understand by the way ;) )

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution myself (with the helpful comments from *markuscosinus*) and will post this here in case anyone has the same problem:

I looked at the implementation of `scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter` (which can be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/feature/peak.py#L25). I twitched the code slightly to work with my data shape and used `footprint = np.ones((size_neighborhood, size_neighborhood, nr_rotations))`.